# Copy a directory into a relative path with shtuil.copytree

Tags: python, directory, shutil

I am trying to copy a directory into some relative path. The original directory have some files, and the issue is that only the files are being copied.

I have the following tree structure

```
./test/f1
./test/f1/asdf
./test/f2
./test/f2/asdf
```

and i want to produce something like this

```
./test/f1
./test/f1/asdf
./test/f2
./test/f2/asdf
./f1/
./f1/asdf
```

To do so, I am running the following

```
>>> shutil.copytree("test/f1", ".", dirs_exist_ok=True)
'.'
```

but that is only copying the `./f1/asdf` file into `.`, so I end up with this

```
./test/f1
./test/f1/asdf
./test/f2
./test/f2/asdf
./asdf
```

what is the correct way to copy the directory? I basically want the same behavior as `cp -R test/f1/ .`

Answer (score 0):

Before

```
.
└── test
    ├── f1
    │   └── asdf
    └── f2
        └── asdf
```

Then run:

```
shutil.copytree('test/f1', 'f1', dirs_exist_ok=True)
```

results in:

```
.
├── f1
│   └── asdf
└── test
    ├── f1
    │   └── asdf
    └── f2
        └── asdf
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: isnt that going to copy also the f2 folder?

Comment: I modified my answer. Note that in your question f2 is not in the original problem statement, so we don't know where it comes from - you might want to edit so it appears in the original tree structure. I hope this edited answer helps!

Comment: Ah right, sorry.When I created the question, I only use f1, but then I realize that if another folder existed, there could be issues, so I change the question, but apparently failed to do so everywhere!

Comment: Thanks for editing the question. Please accept the answer if it works for you. Thanks!